# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - Google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have problem with google chart. I get error in console:

- overview-statistic-chart-ctrl.js:102 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at callback (overview-statistic-chart-ctrl.js:102) at loader.js:242

When I refresh or click on some other link and go back to the same link it's work great. But I get this error only when I first time load page.

This is my code:

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function () {
        var teamNames = $scope.teams.map(team => team.team_name);
        var days = $scope.teams.map(team => team.date_activity);
        var avgMaxHRLastDays = $scope.teams.map(team => team.avgMaxHRLastDays);

        var days = $scope.teams.map(team => team.date_activity);
        var withDates = avgMaxHRLastDays.map(data => data);

        var newArray = matrixTranspose(withDates);

        var dataChart = newArray.map(data => [''].concat(data));

        console.log("dataChart ", dataChart);

        var filled = dataChart.map(data => fillWithZeros(data, $scope.teams.length));

        var dataToVisualize = [
            ["Teams"].concat(teamNames),
        ].concat(filled);

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataToVisualize);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('heartOverviewChart'));
        chart.draw(data, optionsDesktop);
    },
    packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: error is in this line:         var teamNames = $scope.teams.map(team => team.team_name);

Comment: I dunno if is the solution of your problem but i think you need if you didn't add, to call the charts when body is loaded if you didn't add in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.teams` seem to not be set properly (this will default the 'teams' property to `undefined`) So when you are trying to map over the expected 'teams' array you see the error.

Make sure your `$scope` and the properties in `$scope` (here `$scope.teams`) are set properly before you try accessing them in the callback function.

Maybe a couple of log statements or debugging it with a couple of break points might help.

> When I refresh or click on some other link and go back to the same link it's work great.

this might happen because by the time you perform those "other" operations the `$scope.teams` might have the expected value or maybe those "other" operations are setting the `$scope.teams` value.